# How to write script in autohotkey which press Tab+Tab+Tab+Enter+Up+Tab+Enter

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to write an AutoHotKey script to preform the following chain of keyboard actions, when I press a single button on my keyboard:

```
Tab+Tab+Tab+Enter+Up+Tab+Enter
```

How can I detect keyboard actions in order to trigger this, and how do I go about executing the chain of keyboard actions afterwards?

Comment: What code have you already written? Have you checked out the [AutoHotKey documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
Send {Tab 3}
Send {return}
Send {Up}
Send {Tab}
Send {return}
```

Please take a look at [The Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) for an introduction to AHK.